# Unable to vertically align side-by-side child divs within the parent

Tags: html, css, css-float, parent-child

I have three child divs sitting side-by-side inside the parent. The left and right are of a fixed width, whilst the middle is a variable width and needs to resize with the browser. As they are of different heights, I need to vertically align them inside the parent, but I cannot get them to, and they stick to the top. Is there any way I can do this? The height of the child divs are fixed, but the height of the parent should be variable.

CSS:

```
#divMain { width: 100%; min-width:320px; height:400px}
#div1 { width: 100px; height: 200px; float: left; red;vertical-align:middle;display:inline-block; }
#div2 { margin-left: 110px; height: 400px; margin-right: 110px; vertical-align:middle;}
#div3 { width: 100px; height:300px; float: right; vertical-align:middle;display:inline-block;}
```

HTML

```
<div id="divMain">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of vertical-align:middle use line-height property

Comment: I suppose you need a Javascript-free solution?

Comment: Not necessarily, but it would be better if there were a CSS only solution, is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is, using `position: absolute; top: 50%;`, and then applying a negative `margin-top` of half the element's height. It's a very common way of centering vertically. See my answer for a live example.

Comment: @natlines: I saw you un-marked my answer as accepted. Is there an issue with my code?

Comment: No all good, I unclicked it by accident! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a JS-free way of achieving this using `position: absolute` on the side divs:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xa8TW/2/

CSS

```
#divMain {
    width: 100%;
    min-width:320px;
    position: relative;
}
#div1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
}
#div2 {
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 110px;
    background-color: green;
}
#div3 {
    width: 100px;
    height:300px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: -150px;
}
```

HTML can be left unchanged, but it is now also possible to swap the places of `#div2` and `#div3`, since there are no floated elements that require a certain order.

Comment: Line-height: good solution. What if the user want some text inside the divs?

Comment: That was a leftover from an earlier revision of mine. `line-height` is not necessary in this solution and has thusly been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Is the height of DIVs fixed? As it seems from your code the heights are fixed to 400px. If that's true then the solution is very simple - just provide a `margin-top` to `div1` and `div3`.

I've created the fiddle for this and removed some of useless CSS snippets (which do not make nay difference) as well. Have a look

> http://jsfiddle.net/8kv2K/

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned, the height of the child divs are fixed, but the height of the parent should be variable